# Imageresizer with c# Web API

Tags: imageresizer

I was checking Imageresizer S3 Reader2 plugin, and I have the following question.

My app is basically a c# REST API that has a functionality of serving 
photos (resized photos).

Would it be possible to use Imageresizer+Amazon S3 with REST API so I can resize 
photos in with Imageresizer in c# before serving it and without transferring original photo over network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to transfer the original photo from S3 to *your* server (at least once) in order to resize it. The S3Reader2 plugin does this automatically. If you want to prevent repeat requests, look into SourceDiskCache.

Otherwise, that's exactly how ImageResizer+S3Reader2 functions.